# Would deleting activities improve search performance

Tags: activities, contacts

CiviCRM 4.1.5

We have some people convinced that search performance would be speeded up by deleting activities against and individuals record. I have my doubts. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: I recommend you make two copies of your database, and sit them side by side, then delete the historic activities from one, test search times and report your results as an answer! [Sharing a little research](https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/795696d1e8b25b8b9130) can be really useful to the community.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion.

Comment: What was the outcome? You can answer your own question on Stack Exchange :)